# Twitter Bootstrap Jquery code for collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was hoping someone could explain what is happening i the following code taken from Twitter Bootstrap...

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function ( e ) {
      var $this = $(this), href
        , target = $this.attr('data-target')
          || e.preventDefault()
          || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
        , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
      $(target).collapse(option)
    })
  })
```

I use 'on' click with jquery but never with the dot notation after 'click' and never with the []

Thanks for any help in figuring out what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot notation is a namespace.

```js
$('#myElt').on('click.mynamespace',someFunction); // listening
$('#myElt').off('click.mynamespace'); // not listening any more
```

It allows you for example to easily remove all event listeners from one namespace only.

jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names).

---

The second argument is a selector for all elements that have a `data-toggle` attribute equal to `collapse`. [W3C doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) & [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Here is an example of its use

```js
$('#myContainer').on('click','.child',someFunction);
```

If I'm not mistaken, it means that any click event *going* to a `.child` element will be *intercepted* by this listener, whether the `.child` element was created at the time of the binding or not. And the `someFunction` callback will be called.

jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).